# Android DatePicker with current date

Tags: android, date, time, datepicker

I am not getting current date in my datePickerDialog. Always x.xx.1900 :/

Here is my **code:**

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int y = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int m = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int d = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH + Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,d,m,y);
```

and:

```
DialogFragment datePicker = new DateFragment();
    datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

Comment: problem solved getActivity(),this,y(!),m,d(!));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the constructor of `DatePickerDialog` is

```
public DatePickerDialog (Context context, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener callBack, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
```

You should use this :

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
int y = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int m = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int d = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,y,m,d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This to get the The Latest Date

```
public String getDisplayDate(){
    return (dt.getDate()+"/"+(dt.getMonth()+1)+"/"+(dt.getYear()+1900));
}
```

Comment: thank you 4 the hints, i solved it already.. i've been kind of dumb :/ :D